# Is there a simple way to use VB.NET to read a SharePoint Online file without logging in?

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint-online

I inherited a program written in VB.NET.  I want to host the installer and documentation for the program in a SharePoint Online library.  The SPO library allows View/Read-only access to "Everyone except external users" but it does not allow anonymous access.  I want the program to check the SPO library for an updated version when it launches.

I envisioned a simple function like this:

```
Private Function getVersion() As String
  Using client As New WebClient
    getVersion = client.DownloadString("https://companyname.sharepoint.com/site/library/version.txt")
  End Using
End Function
```

where version.txt contains nothing but the current version number.

However, this function throws an IOException stating that the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  I think this is because the SPO site requires authentication.

I don't want to add a user login step solely for this one thing.  This probably means an SPO site that requires authentication is not the ideal place for my version.txt file to reside, but I'm also trying to avoid solutions that require me to jump through hoops and involve others to get it to work.  I'm the only developer for this program, so I'd like to be able to publish an update without having to wait for someone else to do something (like update a web server that I don't have access to).

Suggestions for a simple technique to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SharePoint or `WebClient` specifically, but if the site shares authentication with the local machine login, you can probably set it up to work correctly without prompting for user login.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Using` block, before the line with `DownloadString`, set the `Credentials` of your `WebClient`:

```
Private Function getVersion() As String
  Using client As New WebClient
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    getVersion = client.DownloadString("https://companyname.sharepoint.com/site/library/version.txt")
  End Using
End Function
```

The `DefaultCredentials` will be the credentials of the currently logged in Windows user.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials?view=net-5.0) on `System.Net.WebClient`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  This seems like the right approach, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same exception.  I also tried "client.UseDefaultCredentials = True" with the same result.